# R shiny leaflet maps do not load for more than one browser instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, leaflet

We're creating a webapp (http://52.2.13.97:3838/Boston-Inspections/) that uses a `leaflet` map. `shiny-server` is being run on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance.

We noticed (and you can probably notice from the link) that the map does not update as it should when the `shiny` inputs change. However, they do update for the very first instance of `shiny` on the EC2 instance.

Does anyone know why the map would properly render for the very instance, but for every subsequent instance, the map simply does not load/update? If it helps, all of these 'instances' seem to run in the same worker process on the EC2 instance (ie. multiple tabs running the webapp will all be contained under the same process via `ps aux`).

Update: if it helps, we've tried upgrading to a t2.large instance and had exactly the same issue. We don't think it's a performance issue. We also checks /var/log/shiny-server and found nothing out of the ordinary while the webapp is running.

Comment: It's working fine for me in two instances of Chrome running at the same time and with different checkbox options selected.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Did the free text search as well? Neither is working for me and someone else.